# How to check hcheck_interval value of a SAN disk

Tags: aix, disk

http://aix4admins.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/kdb-kdb-kernel-debugger-and-kdb-command.html

**Question:** The URL writes about local disks. But How can I check it for SAN disks? Using AIX 6.

This setting would automatically restore the failed paths after a SAN issue.

Comment: This settings does not automatically restore anything, it only defines the time interval after which active disks are checked. See http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_61/com.ibm.aix.osdevice/devpathctrlmodatts.htm?lang=en for details on the setting.
You should also make sure to set hcheck_mode to nonactive (which means paths to inactive disks will also be checked, the name of that setting is a bit misleading)
For more information on lsattr see https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.cmds3/lsattr.htm

Answer (score 0):

A very similar site (http://aix4admins.blogspot.com/2011/09/lsdev-cc-disk-what-kind-of-disks-we.html?m=1) has instructions for querying an hdisk, whether local or SAN.

```
lsattr -El hdiskNN
```